# How to re-run an exisiting AWS batch translation job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, translate

I created a batch translation job. Now I need to re-run the job again to translate another file. Can anyone guide me on how to rerun the existing batch translation job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS has no option to  re-run an existing translation batch job .